# How to detect gimbal beacon is working or not in android? (Gimbal Proximity Beacon Series 10)

Tags: android, android-ibeacon, gimbal

I've recently bought new **Gimbal Proximity Beacon Series 10** and now just want to check if it is working (can transmit signal) or not.

And since it doesn't have **TURN ON** / **TURN OFF** button, so i decide to replace the battery with the new one (just to make sure it's still can be use).

Then, I've add/activate the beacon in my [Gimbal Manager](https://manager.gimbal.com) account, insert the factory ID, but it seems still not yet detected since the **'unknown'** status was shown in *battery level* and *firmware*. You can look at the following pict :

[image]

Is there any android app to detect beacon/gimbal beacon? (just to check if the beacon is working or not)

Anyone have ever work with gimbal beacon before?
Any advice/clue would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a developer, the best way would be to have a look at, and try to run, the sample application which is distributed with the  [Android SDK](https://manager.gimbal.com/download_sdk?id=215). 
You only need to set your Gimbal API key. The line in the Activity, or the Service, in the sample application should look like `Gimbal.setApiKey(this.getApplication(), "## PLACE YOUR API KEY HERE ##");`.

It may not be the fastest way, but it would give an insight on how to use the Gimbal SDK in your application. If you have Internet access enabled while running the application, the state of your beacons will be updated in the Gimbal Manager, so you could have the information about the battery level and the time your beacons were last detected by the application.

The **unknown** status in the Gimbal Manager just shows that no application has detected your beacons, with the API key that was given to you.

If you still just want to check if your beacons are working, you could try the application *BeaconFinder* which can be found on the Google Play Store (disclaimer: I am not associated with the developer/application in any way.)